# How do I close all popups with .removeclass or .toggleclass

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to close the myPopup2 div if it's showing and vice versa.  Right now if I click on myPopup2 Div first and then click  myPopup1 div second it goes underneath and I need myPopup2 div to close.

** The function to open popup 1 should close popup 2 if it's showing and vice versa

CodePen: https://codepen.io/shopmaster/pen/ZEWxrVx

I've tried this

```
function myFunction1() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup1");
  popup.classList.toggle("show"); 
  
  if ( document.getElementById("myPopup2").classList.contains("show"))
  myFunction2();
  
}
```

but that didn't work.  Any suggestions?

I have the following CSS

```
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
   position: fixed; 
  top: 70%;
  left: 40%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */


/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible; 
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
```

My HTML looks like this

```
<!-- DIV  POPUP #1 -->
<div class="popup">
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup1">
  <span onclick="myFunction1()"
      class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
  <b>1. Fiscal Target and Rules:<br> Does the government have fiscal institutions to support fiscal sustainability and to facilitate medium-term planning for public investment?</b>
  <br><br>
  <p>1.a. Is there a target or limit for government to ensure debt sustainability?</p>
  <p>1.b. Is fiscal policy guided by one or more permanent fiscal rules?</p>
  <p>1.c. Is there a medium-term fiscal framework (MTFF) to align budget preparation with fiscal policy?</p>
  
  </span>
</div>

<!-- DIV  POPUP #2 -->
<div class="popup">
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup2">
  <span onclick="myFunction2()"
      class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
  <b>2. Fiscal Target and Rules: Does the government have fiscal institutions to support fiscal sustainability and to facilitate medium-term planning for public investment?</b>
  <br><br>
  <p>1.a. Is there a target or limit for government to ensure debt sustainability?</p>
  <p>1.b. Is fiscal policy guided by one or more permanent fiscal rules?</p>
  <p>1.c. Is there a medium-term fiscal framework (MTFF) to align budget preparation with fiscal policy?</p>
  
  </span>
</div>
```

My Javascript looks like this:

```
<script>
// When the user clicks on <div>, open the popup
function myFunction1() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup1");
  popup.classList.toggle("show"); 
  
 
}
function myFunction2() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup2");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>
```

Comment: The function to open popup 1 should close popup 2 and vice versa.

Comment: In the css part, `.popup .show` should be `.popup.show` (without a space) - see [css](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) With the space, you are styling any object with a class of "show" that is a child of an object with a class of "popup".  Additionally, if you only want to show one div at a time, you have to toggle the class on the other as well.  However, if both are already hidden,you may have to use something other than toggle.  Perhaps: popup.className="show" and popup.className = "" - this will replace it with either "show" or an empty string.

Comment: @ATD His IDs are in the inner elements of the popup, so `.popup .show` will work in his case.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you another approach to these popups. I have commented the code. If it is unclear, please add a comment.

This way you can add many popups without changing your js.

PS: Please note that I have changed some CSS for the snippet to be working. Also, some HTML is changed to accomplish the idea of multiple popups, which will be ideal for your case with many popups in this pie chart.

```js
const popups = document.querySelectorAll('.popup');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.js-toggle-modal');
const closeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.js-modal-close');

const closeModals = () => {
  // Iterate through all popups and remove class show
  popups.forEach(popup => {
    popup.classList.remove('show');
  })
}

closeButtons.forEach(button => {
  // Close all popups on close button click
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    closeModals();
  })
});

buttons.forEach(button => {
  // Cache target of each button
  const target = document.querySelector(button.getAttribute('data-target'));

  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Hide all active popups
    closeModals();

    // Show current target popup
    target.classList.add('show');
  });
});
```

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .3s, visibility .3s;
}


/* The actual popup */

.popup .popup__text {
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
}


/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */

.popup.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn js-toggle-modal" data-target="#popup1">Open popup1</button>
<button class="btn js-toggle-modal" data-target="#popup2">Open popup2</button>

<div class="popup" id="popup1">
  <div class="popup__text">
    <button class="popup__close js-modal-close" data-target="#popup2">&times;</button>

    <b>1. Fiscal Target and Rules:<br> Does the government have fiscal institutions to support fiscal sustainability and to facilitate medium-term planning for public investment?</b>
    <br><br>
    <p>1.a. Is there a target or limit for government to ensure debt sustainability?</p>
    <p>1.b. Is fiscal policy guided by one or more permanent fiscal rules?</p>
    <p>1.c. Is there a medium-term fiscal framework (MTFF) to align budget preparation with fiscal policy?</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="popup" id="popup2">
  <div class="popup__text">
    <button class="popup__close js-modal-close" data-target="#popup2">&times;</button>

    <b>2. Fiscal Target and Rules: Does the government have fiscal institutions to support fiscal sustainability and to facilitate medium-term planning for public investment?</b>
    <br><br>
    <p>1.a. Is there a target or limit for government to ensure debt sustainability?</p>
    <p>1.b. Is fiscal policy guided by one or more permanent fiscal rules?</p>
    <p>1.c. Is there a medium-term fiscal framework (MTFF) to align budget preparation with fiscal policy?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using the following in the chart javascript:

`
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.events.on("hit", function(event){
openPop(event.target.dataItem.category);
})

function openPop(category){
if(category == "1. Fiscal Targets and Rules"){

var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup1");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}

if(category == "2. National and Sectoral \n Planning"){
   var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup2");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
` @Rado